# Apache VirtualDocumentRoot, MAMP, .local domain & xip.io?

Tags: macos, apache, mamp

I have a problem making [xip.io](http://xip.io/) works. I have set up my machine to use virtualhosts with MAMP `.local` domain name.

this is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
UseCanonicalName Off

<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/<myusername>/Sites/%-1/%-2+/build
    <Directory "/Users/<myusername>/Sites">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access for example `http://project.local.<my local ip>.xip.io` it doesn't work while `http://project.local` works. How can I fix this?

Also, I have read that the `.local` domain on Mac can cause some problems, is this true?

Comment: On OSX .local is used by Bonjour for local discovery of ips by name without using DNS (see [RFC 6762](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6762)

Comment: Have you edited the hosts file?

Comment: yes, my Hosts file is edited

Answer (score 1):

I use MAMP Pro and the file `httpd-vhosts.conf` does not contain this setting, but in the app I have this:

[image: ServerAlias example.*xip.io]

The host is `http://plugins.dev` and if my memory serves me well, it's all that's needed to have it working.